# Call onClick from js file from Blade file (Laravel 6)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am importing a script at the bottom of my Blade file, which injects the JS at the top of the HTML markup, just after the open `<body>` tag.

This script is importing correctly as I have defined it in Webpack and I am logging out some text to the console, which is appearing fine.

I would like to have an onClick function in this script file, e.g.

`<button onClick=testFunction()>Click Me</button>`

And the function in the js file looks like:

```
console.log('test import file');

function testFunction() {
    console.log('button has been clicked')
}
```

However, when I click the button on the page, I get:

> settings:264 Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Why is my markup able to read this file (to log to the console `test import file`) but the function testFunction is not found?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using a function under `console.log()`

It would be :

```js
function testFunction() {
  console.log('button has been clicked');
}
```

```html
<button onClick=testFunction()>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying - I don't understand what you mean. On my button, I am trying to run testFunction, and the script is already imported at the top of the page above the button.

Comment: @party dont import on the top. Add this `js` in the bottom under `<script>` tag

Comment: In this case position don't cause any issues define it in the `<head>` or in the `footer` and then call it like this `<script>function testFunction(){ console.log('message'); }</script>` and then call it with any button like `<button onClick="testFunction()"></button>` it will work.

Comment: Also tried at the bottom, same result. @MohsinAbbas I need to have it in a different file not in my blade file.

Comment: OK so you want to write `JS` in different file and then include it in your blade right? and how are you including it in your blade?

Comment: @MohsinAbbas yep, I import it like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/themeSwitcher.js') }}"></script>` and I know it's importing because I am gettingt he console log. I just don't know how to call the function in that file on an onclick event.

Comment: Try this code `<button onClick="testFunction()"></button>`

Comment: Remove line `console.log('test import file');` you can't import a file like this.  use only

`function testFunction() {
    console.log('button has been clicked')
}` hope you understand?